# Formik react-select unable to get selected value

Tags: formik, react-select

I am using Formik + react-select to get and validate a form field.

Here is the code playground [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-frog-xwbqp6?file=/src/App.jsx).

Its currently giving an error when i select an element from drop down.
What is the right way to set the value for a selected field.?

I tried debugging in the browser and it seems the `selectedGroup` is coming out as `undefined`.

I have tried looking into similar questions, which suggest:
`setFieldValue()` and few other options but none seem to work.

Edit:
Additionally, if I use below, it now sets the validation field but the dropdown doesnt show the select value.

```
onChange={selectedOption => {
                            console.log("sel opt is", selectedOption);
                            handleBusinessCat(selectedOption.value);
                            
                            // validation.handleChange("businessCategory")(selectedOption.value);
                            validation.setFieldValue("businessCategory", selectedOption.value);
                            // let event = {target: {name: 'businessCategory', value: selectedOption.value}}
                            // validation.handleChange(event)
                          }}
```

Answer (score 0):

code playground really helped me to figure it out.

First change your businessCategory shape to this.

```
   businessCategory: Yup.object()
    .shape({
      value: Yup.string(),
      label: Yup.string()
    })
    .required("Please Select Your Business Category"),
```

Next step is your select onChange method will be this

```
onChange={(e) => {
                   validation.setFieldValue("businessCategory", e);
                 }}
```

Now it handle the changes but you can not see in select component because you have to give the correct value to select.

```
value={validation.values.businessCategory}
```

It worked on playground. Have a good day!